# simplify oracle query without substr and union function

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to partition column 1 value into multiple values based on character length.

**Example:** 
In address column first 10 characters should load in first row. Second 10 characters should load in 2nd row based on empno,empname.

**source table:**

```
empid:1 empname:aaa       address: SONY/SB/743-0198/23-7.SCU P/N 743-0198-003. MOD DOT
```

Target table:

```
empid:1 empname:aaa       address:SONY/SB/74
empid:1 empname:aaa       address:3-0198/23-
empid:1 empname:aaa       address:SCU P/N 74.
```

I tried it to using substr fun.

```
select empno,empname,substr(address,1,10) from emp
union
select empno,empname,substr(address,11,10) from emp;
```

Rather than using substr and union is their any other way to acheive this.

Comment: That's a job for an ETL tool, not SQL queries

Answer (score 1):

If you started with a list of numbers, you could do:

```
with n as (
        select 1 as n from dual union all
        select 11 from dual union all
        select 21 from dual
       )
select e.empno, e.empname, substr(e.address, n.n, 10)
from emp e join
     n
     on length(address) <= n.n + 10;
```

You can generate the values for `n` instead of listing them individually, using a recursive subquery, `connect by level`, or by using `rownum` on a table.  For three values, though, it is easy enough to type them in.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt still using substr, but not union:

```
with w as
(
  select 1 + 10 * (level - 1) n
  from dual
  connect by level <= 3
)
select t.empid, t.empname, substr(t.address, w.n, 10) address
from w
cross join test t
;
```